# what's the equiv part of hapi request.state for express?

Tags: node.js, express, hapi.js

In hapi, there was a state obj for request request.state.

What's the equivalent part in express? req.session?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not familiar with Hapi but from [docs](http://hapijs.com/api#serverstatename-options) I understand `state` corresponds to http cookies. If my understanding is correct, then in expressjs you can use [cookie-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser) middleware to get the cookies sent by client using `req.cookies`

```
var express      = require('express')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

var app = express()
app.use(cookieParser())

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log("Cookies: ", req.cookies)
})

app.listen(8080)
```

If you want to set state or in other words cookie then just set it on the response i.e. `res` like this. [Reference](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.cookie)

```
var cookieConfig = {}; // set config options here like domain, httpOnly, maxAge etc.
res.cookie('key', 'value', cookieConfig);
```